# .NET SpinLock not releasing Thread.BeginCriticalSection

Tags: .net, spinlock

Using .NET reflector, I find that the **SpinLock** structure has a lot of cases where it calls **Thread.BeginCriticalRegion** and doesn't call **Thread.EndCriticalRegion**.
For example, in the public function SpinLock.Enter(ref bool lockTaken) (.NET 4.0):

```
// ...
Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.m_owner, managedThreadId, owner, ref lockTaken) == owner)
    return;  // <--- !!
Thread.EndCriticalRegion();
// ...
```

In another case, SpinLock.Exit seems to call **Thread.EndCriticalRegion** without having called **Thread.BeginCriticalRegion**.

```
public void Exit(bool useMemoryBarrier)
{
    if (this.IsThreadOwnerTrackingEnabled && !this.IsHeldByCurrentThread)
        throw ...

    if (useMemoryBarrier)
    {
        if (this.IsThreadOwnerTrackingEnabled)
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.m_owner, 0);
        else
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref this.m_owner);
    }
    else if (this.IsThreadOwnerTrackingEnabled)
        this.m_owner = 0;
    else
    {
        int owner = this.m_owner;
        this.m_owner = owner - 1;
    }
    Thread.EndCriticalRegion();   // <--- ??
}
```

So the question: do any problems ensue from not balancing calls to Begin/EndCriticalRegion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the Begin/End calls *do* balance if the lock is actually taken and then released by calling Exit(). The calls to mark the critical region are necessary to let the CLR know that thread interruptions may be damaging while a SpinLock is acquired. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.begincriticalregion.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for this info; I didn't think of that because I instinctively assumed that a CriticalRegion shouldn't be held over unpredictable external code.